# Why is my golang app returning no Postgres records if compiled without error and returns no errors?

Tags: postgresql, go

The situation looks like on this picture: https://pasteboard.co/HSsFIgn.png

I have PostgreSQL portable 10.1 and golang 1.10.2 portable. I wrote simple program to fetch data from database and I got no response The code is this: I have no compilation errors, I can run dbapp.exe and I get nothing as a result, please see upper pasted pic or code lower: Thanks for any hints.

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "log"
)

const (
    DB_USER     = "postgres"
    DB_PASSWORD = ""
    DB_NAME     = "golang"
)

func main() {
    dbinfo := fmt.Sprintf("user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable",
        DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", dbinfo)
    checkErr(err)
    defer db.Close()
    var (
        id int
        name string
    )
    rows, err := db.Query("select id, song from music where id = 1")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    for rows.Next() {
        err := rows.Scan(&id, &name)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        log.Println(id, name)
    }
    err = rows.Err()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func checkErr(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the query `select id, song from music where id = 1` against the `golang` DB in your database actually produce results?

Comment: Are you sure you're running the right version of the application ? With a code producing absolutely no output it's hard to know...

Comment: The go code, db connection params, and db data seem to be all ok. Try to recompile the binary and run it again. Additionally also check postgres' logs to see if it's receiving the query or not (you may have to first enable the logs if they're not already and then restart the server).

Comment: ok, I ve got it, the problem was sql.Open strings, fianl code works like this without problem:
package main
    import (
        "database/sql"
        "fmt"
        _ "github.com/lib/pq"
        "log"
        )
    func main() {
  //necessary to change sql.Open strings
        db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "user=postgres dbname=golang port=5432 sslmode=disable")
        checkErr(err)
        defer db.Close()
  var (
   id int
   name string
  )...and so on like upper...

Answer (score 0):

Solution is sql.Open string, it was broken or something, now it works this way:

```
package main
    import (
        "database/sql"
        "fmt"
        _ "github.com/lib/pq"
        "log"
        )
    func main() {
        //necessary to change sql.Open strings
        db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "user=postgres dbname=golang port=5432 sslmode=disable")
        checkErr(err)
        defer db.Close()
        var (
            id int
            name string
        )
        rows, err := db.Query("select id, song from music where id = 1")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        defer rows.Close()
        for rows.Next() {
            err := rows.Scan(&id, &name)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            log.Println(id, name)
        }
        err = rows.Err()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
    func checkErr(err error) {
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            panic(err)
        }
    }
```